# Search for used columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Background:

We have two directories of Crystal Reports for both the web side of an application and Win32 side.  Both front-ends share the same database and for the most part, the same reports....it just so happens they are in different locations.

Question:

We have to change a column in many of the reports from one to another and want to know if there is an application, technique or way to search all the reports for the existence of this column so that we know how many reports we have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up getting the report definitions done for each report (which we needed to do anyway) and save them in one area.  We then used the program available at this website: http://www.ml-consult.co.uk which is called Crystal Reports Documentor which will build us a comma delimited file in which we can search for reports that use specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to make use of this project: [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/).